# access rights of a file in octal format

Tags: solaris

I wonder if there is command which will give you access rights of any file you provide.
There stat related command but it is not accessible in solaris.

```
stat -c %a /etc/passwd
```

Is there any equivalent command in solaris ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pkgproto`:

`/usr/bin/pkgproto <filename>`

Comment: That's not what that's for.

Answer (score 3):

`stat` is available for solaris in the gnucore package.